# PHP: Passing selected list value to another variable in the same page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form, having two list boxes and  based on the selected field from the first list, I have to fetch data from the database to create second list box.

I am trying to acheive this with post method, but unable to understand why mey second list is not populating with data...

**PHP to fetch data for second list box**

```
if (isset($_POST['val']))
{
    $value = $_POST['val'];
    $smt3 = $db->prepare('select floor from test where name_id =?');
    $smt3->execute(array($value));
    $HF_id = $smt3->fetchAll();
}
```

**HTML to for the list boxes**

```
<select class="Name" name="Profile_Name1" id="PC1"> 
            <option value="A">AA</option>
            <option value="B">BB</option>
            <option value="c">CC</option>
            <option value="d">DD</option>
</select>
        <label>Home Floor </label>
        <select name="Home_Floor" id="hfid">    <br />
            <option value="">Home_Floor</option>
                <?php foreach ($HF_id as $row){echo '<option value="' . $row['floor'] . '">' . $row ['floor'] . '</option>';}?>
</select>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#PC1').on('click', function() {
        $.post('user_info1.php', 'val=' + $(this).val(), function (response) {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'user_info1.php', //This is the current doc
        type: "POST",
        data: ({val: + $(this).val()}),
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
```

Comment: what does `+` do?

Comment: You need only`$('#PC1').on("change",function() {$.post('user_info1.php', {val: $(this).val()}, function(response) { /* use response - do NOT ajax here too */ });});` and your PHP needs to return proper JSON

Comment: @mplungjan I tried this also , but its also not making any difference.

Comment: It certainly does. Use my code and then fix the other problems. Like not returning JSON from the user_info1.php

Comment: You are calling two ajax ($.post and $.ajax) just use one like @mplungjan said. Remove all $.ajax and inside function (response) { ** HERE ** }  you can get **response** from user_info1.php... but first you have to echo something in user_info1.php...

Comment: @Roy Hi,user_info1.php is the same page where we have the jquery and lists.I want to do this in the same page .`  $('#PC1').click(function() { $.post('user_info1.php',{val :$(this).val()},function(response){ });   }); `  





*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to expect the post function to trigger a loading of the page specified by the URL parameter.

Try something along the lines of this:

### HTML

```
<select class="Name" name="Profile_Name1" id="PC1"> 
    <option value="A">AA</option>
    <option value="B">BB</option>
    <option value="C">CC</option>
    <option value="D">DD</option>
</select>
<label>Home Floor </label>
<select name="Home_Floor" id="hfid">

</select>
```

### loaddata.php

```
if (isset($_POST['val']))
{
    $value = $_POST['val'];
    $smt3 = $db->prepare('select floor from test where name_id =?');
    $smt3->execute(array($value));
    $HF_id = $smt3->fetchAll();
    $HF_array=array();
    foreach ($HF_id as $row)
    {
        $HF_array[]=$row['floor'];
    }
}
echo json_encode($HF_array);
```

### javascript/jquery

```
jQuery('#PC1').on('click', function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'loaddata.php', 
        type: "POST",
        data: ({val: + $(this).val()}),
        success: function(data){
            //data should come as JSON string in the form of ['item1','item2','item3'] use JSON.parse to convert to object:
            jQuery.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, datavalue) {   
                jQuery('#hfid').append(
                    jQuery('<option>', { value : datavalue })
                    .text(datavalue)
                );//end of append
            });//end of each
        }//end of success function
    });//end of ajax datastruct and ajax call
});//end of on-click-function
```

Comment: Thank you  @denvercoder... You saved me big time !!